# LUIS API for removing entity marked from utterance

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am building an application using LUIS API's. I have implemented all major functionalities except remove marked entity from utterance. I could not find any API related to it.

There is an API to remove roles and Delete entity, which is not my requirement

I am refering this [link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f)

The expected results is removing the marked entity from utterance. Any links or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check what LUIS portal is doing when you do such an action (removing an entity from an utterance), you can see that they use `Add label` method in fact, to overwrite the existing utterance.

Called URL is `https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/example`

[image: Sample]

Lien to the documentation of this method is here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08

Comment: So we have to again send the utterance ..but without entity right??

Comment: Yes! And with the same id, to be overwritten